# Measurement Errors in Gaussian Process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

If we consider a Gaussian process for one-dimensional variable
$$
S(X) \sim GP(\mu,\sigma^2K),
$$
where $K$ is the exponential kernel ($K(x,y) = e^{-\frac{||x-y||_2}{\phi}}$),

I am wondering how can we find a new process $R(x)$ that
$$ 
R(x) = \frac{1}{2\theta}\int_{x-\theta}^{x+\theta}S(z)dz
$$
and figure out its mean, variance, and kernel function?

Answer (score 1):

It may be good to consider that
$$
\int_{x_1-\theta}^{x_1 - \theta} \int_{x_2 - \theta}^{x_2 + \theta} e^{- \frac{|z_1 - z_2|}{\phi}}dz_1dz_2.
$$

Comment: But I don't quite understand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).